# SVN commit, got a revision number, but edits did not go through

Tags: svn, revision-history

I made changes to a file on my local computer. I svn committed the changes and it says it's sending the file and returned with a revision number. Everything seems normal.

I checked the site, nothing changed.  I clear cache; nothing. Then I ssh into the server only to discover that the timestamp on the file was a day old! I then checked my svn url and I see the most up-to-date revision number. But when I drill down to the file, none of my changes were taken!

How is this even possible? It seems like it must have done something if it gave me a revision number and had 'Sending [filename]' when it was committing.  But I can't find those changes anywhere as if it committed into the ether.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: Check the log and review the diff between the previous revision and the revision you committed.

Comment: Hey, dude! Who told you that from commit automagically imply update of anything?

Comment: Until you run `svn update` (by any mechanism) on the server you ssh'd into, nothing will change there.